# How does energy loss work in Redstone Energy Conduits

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

[image]

In this situation you see I have my conduits linearly running along the line of engines. It says on the wiki that the conduits have a 5% energy loss, implemented at points where energy enters the line. Does this mean that with 5 entry points linearly spread (like I have here) that by the time the energy reaches me I've lost 25% of my energy, or still just 5%?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The moment energy enters a Redstone Energy Conduits or a Redstone Energy Cell from the outside, you lose 5% power.

Once energy is in the system, there is no loss. Moving Energy between Redstone Energy Conduits and/or Redstone Energy Cells is lossless, and there is no distance based loss. So your loss is 5% from each engine, which (because math) is 5% of your total energy output, not 25%.

Answer (score 4):

You have five entry points, and at each point, energy passing through decreases by 5%. However, you are not losing 25% of your energy, since any energy entering your system only passes through one entry point, not all five.